# Anchors requiring multiple clicks to fire

Tags: html, css

'This is bizarre bug. I have CSS3 anchors/buttons, which I've continued to strip properties out of, that sometimes require multiple clicks to fire. I've never seen anything like it.

http://votizen.com

Sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't. So it's very tough to pin down. If anyone is interested in helping me, check out the page and the source code on the large 'Sign in with Facebook' or 'Sign in with Twitter' buttons.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this happening in a particular browser? beautiful buttons btw.

Comment: Which links on the page? Which browsers have you tried? What platform were you working on?

Comment: it did happen to me (chrome latest - ubuntu)

Comment: Tried a few times in Chrome and FF (Win7) but couldn't reproduce. Could it be  Twitter/Facebook API's not responding/timing out/being overloaded sometimes? I've had it happen now and again when testing in the past

Comment: Thank you guys, my last reported case was Chrome/Mac, but I've seen it happen in Safari. First I stripped out the CSS3 transforms that were creating the 'press effect' replacing with standard relative positioning, and I also stripped out the CSS3 background gradients. Next I'm thinking about moving to a anchor/button + span strategy. It's like chasing a ghost. Sometimes it is definitely Facebook time-out, but I have seen sometimes in Firebug that the page doesn't register the click.

Comment: I've only had it happen when pressing the button and releasing while moving the mouse. Doesn't matter if the movement is on the button itself or moving out of it. This is on Chrome for Mac

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that if you click on the very top of the buttons they move down a few pixels. Browsers act when you *release the mouse* (mouseup), and by the time you do it the button is out of the target.

You could either hijack the anchor behavior and make it act on mousedown with js, not have them displace onclick (which would be a shame), or displace them by some other method (such as a top padding).